# Using regex for input validation

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I know the following isn't the most efficient implementation (I could, after all, run regex_match() right in main() ) but it should still work, at least from my limited understanding.

I'm trying to use  in C++11 to validate some input for dicerolls. I used expresso to build the regular expressions, and it validates it within expresso just fine. Why would it fail within this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool regexValidate (string expr, string teststring) 
{
    regex ex(expr);
    if (regex_match(teststring,ex)) {
        return true;
        cout << "true";
    } else if (regex_match (teststring,regex("^\s*\d*d\d*\s*$"))) {
        return true;
        cout << "true";
    }
    return false;
}

int main() 
{
    char    choice;             // menu option selected by user
    bool    isExit = false;     // Is the user ready to exit?         

    // test code
    string  diceexpr = "^\s*\d{1,}d\d{1,}\s*$";
    string  teststr = "10d10";
    string  teststr1 = "1d10";
    string  teststr2 = " 10d10 ";

    cout << teststr << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    cout << teststr1 << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr1)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    cout << teststr2 << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr2)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
10d10 is  invalid!
1d10 is  invalid!
 10d10  is  invalid!

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 291ms)
```

**UPDATE**

Corrected my code and changed it to use the boost library for regular expressions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

bool regexValidate (string expr, string teststring) 
{
    boost::regex ex(expr);
    if ( boost::regex_match (teststring,ex) ) {
        cout << "true";
        return true;
    //} else if (regex_match (teststring,regex("^\s*\d*d\d*\s*$"))) {
    //    cout << "true";
    //    return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string  diceexpr = "^\\s*\\d{1,}d\\d{1,}\\s*$";
    string  teststr = "10d10";
    string  teststr1 = "1d10";
    string  teststr2 = " 10d10 ";

    cout << teststr << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    cout << teststr1 << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr1)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    cout << teststr2 << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr2)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given the following output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: As a side note, in regexValidate, you're never going to output "true" -- you need to move these before the return statement.

Comment: Oops, newbie mistake. Corrected, but the output remains unchanged.

Comment: Your updated code (with `std` substituted for `boost`) [runs when compiled with clang](http://rextester.com/FLV28061) or [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/VSH66200), but [fails when compiled with GCC](http://rextester.com/AJEY51377)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> string  diceexpr = "^\s*\d{1,}d\d{1,}\s*$";

This doesn't do what you think it does. In a string literal, `"\s"` is the same as `"s"` (you should be seeing compiler warnings about unrecognized escape sequences), while `"\\s"` represents two characters, backslash and `'s'`.

Double up all backslashes, or else use a raw string literal for your regular expression, as in

```
string  diceexpr = R"(^\s*\d{1,}d\d{1,}\s*$)";
```

Comment: main.cpp:21:24: error: 'r' was not declared in this scope
     string  diceexpr = r"(^\s*\d{1,}d\d{1,}\s*$)";

Comment: Indeed you are right that I was seeing compiler errors, but didn't know what to make of them.
Also, on the regex definition within the else-if statement in regexValidate, changing to double backslashes threw this:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)

Comment: Apparently, your compiler (which you never mentioned) doesn't fully support C++11, and in particular doesn't support raw string literals. So it's plan B for you - writing "\\" for  a literal backslash character. As to the exception - somehow, you managed to botch the syntax of the regular expression. Show the code you have now.

Comment: Actually looked up raw string literals on the side (sometimes it helps just to have something to look up!) and it turns out R must be capitalized -- at least in NetBeans with GCC. I got the exact same error with the double backslashing, which caused me to trip over the fact that GCC apparently supports regex quite poorly. I'm downloading the boost library to try and correct that, then I'll report back with corrected code and outputs.

Comment: Edited code posted, but now the code will not complile. Now using the boost library.

Comment: Fixed the compile error, question updated accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it does have to be a capital `R`. Sorry, my bad. I'll update the answer.